# Event Click on Pie with highslide

Tags: .net, highlight, highcharts

I'm using this code for a highstock, but I want use it for a Pie, can I do it? cause is not working :/

```
url = ...
$.get(url, function (data) {
          hs.htmlExpand(null, {
          pageOrigin: {
          x: pageX,
          y: pageY
     },
     headingText: title,
     maincontentText: data
     });
});
```

I tried adding that code directly in the click function, and with this:

```
.AddJavascripFunction("test", 
                "hs.htmlExpand(null, {" +
                    "pageOrigin: {"+
                    "},"+
                    "headingText: '...: '," +
                    "maincontentText: 'msje'"+
                "});"
        )
```

But refresh the page (I dont know why) and dont show me the window. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should works, take look at example:

http://jsfiddle.net/tkEwD/2/

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2010'
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
    });
```